# d3.js line numbers in rows of rects

Tags: d3.js, svg, rect

and i don't know how add text in this enter method
it's my JSON

```
var json = [{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg11","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg12","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg13","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg14","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg15","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg16","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg17","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg18","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg19","svgRow":1,"svgX":0,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg21","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg22","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg23","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg24","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg25","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg26","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg27","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg28","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":490,"svgCol":8},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg29","svgRow":2,"svgX":70,"svgY":560,"svgCol":9},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg31","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":0,"svgCol":1},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg32","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":70,"svgCol":2},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg33","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":140,"svgCol":3},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg34","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":210,"svgCol":4},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg35","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":280,"svgCol":5},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg36","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":350,"svgCol":6},{"Id":0,"svgId":"svg37","svgRow":3,"svgX":140,"svgY":420,"svgCol":7}]
```

And i create rects in my page

```
d3.json(url, function (json) {

var canvas = d3.selectAll("#test")
.append("svg")
.attr("id", "svg1")
.attr("width", 1000)
.attr("height", 800);


var rects = canvas
            .append('g')
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(json)
            .enter()
                .append('rect','1')
                .attr({
                    'x': function (data, index) {                                     
                        return data.svgX;                           
                    },
                    'y': function (data, index) {
                        return data.svgY;
                    },
                    'id': function (data, index) {
                        return data.svgId
                    },
                    'width': function (data, index) {
                        return 50
                    },
                    'height': function (data, index) {
                        return 50
                    },
                    'fill': function (data, index) {
                        return '#006699'
                    },                       

                })
```

})

How i can set row number before every row? i think add text or div before every row? but how? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add column to each row 
First group all the json data on the basis of row like shown below

```
var rows = d3.nest().key(function (d) {
    return d.svgCol;//grouping on basis of svgCol
}).rollup(function (d) {
    return d3.max(d, function (l) {
        return l.svgY;//returning the Y of each row
    });
}).entries(json);//json is the full dataset.
```

This will generate the following JSON

```
    [{"key":"1","values":0},{"key":"2","values":70},
{"key":"3","values":140},{"key":"4","values":210},
{"key":"5","values":280},{"key":"6","values":350},
{"key":"7","values":420},{"key":"8","values":490},
{"key":"9","values":560}]
```

Using the above JSON make the text like this:

```
canvas.append('g')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(rows)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr({
    'x': function (data, index) {
        return 0;
    },
        'y': function (data, index) {
        return data.values + 10;
    }
}).text(function (d) {
    return d.key;
})
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/vLubhrqa/)

Hope this helps!